# Why do the numbers not coincide?

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

$$A095983$$

Number of biconnected labeled graphs on n nodes.

$$0, 0, 1, 10, 253, 11968, 1047613$$

$0\ 0$

$1\ 0$

$2\ 1$

$3\ 10$

$4\ 253$

$5\ 11968$

$6\ 1047613$

My enumeration with free turbo pascal gives the following result :

$3\ 1$

$4\ 10$

$5\ 238$

$6\ 11368$

$7\ 1014888$

I do not know why the numbers do not coincide. It seems that OEIS produced a shift
of the numbers, but even after the correction the numbers do not coincide. 
Perhaps the problem has to do with the formulation "on n nodes" instead of
"with n nodes". I counted the 2-vertex-connected undirected labeled graphs,
which should be the same as biconnected graphs. My graphs were undirected, could
it be that the graphs in OEIS are directed ?

It would be great if someone would at least check the case $n=5$, so that I know
if I made a mistake in my program.

Comment: Can you post your code somewhere?  Without knowing what your code is up to, it's hard to say what you're doing wrong.

Comment: The numbers your program is giving appear to be this: https://oeis.org/A013922.

Comment: So, I seem to have made it right. But what do the numbers mean then ?

Comment: It appears that the first sequence is the number of non-isomorphic graphs while you count labelled biconnected graphs?